# How to compare dates for a nested dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Data={
    0:{
       'country1': "Ryan lives in America",
       'country_one': "5",
       'med_dict':{
          0: {
              'endDate': "732",
              'endTime': "89",
             }
       },
     },
    1: {
        'country1': "Sam lives in america",
        'country_three': "90",
        'med_dict': {
          0: {
              'endDate': "245",
              'endTime': "222",
              }
        },

    }
}

res = [v1['country1'] for k1, v1 in Data.items()]
print(res)
```

I have got the output as `['Ryan lives in America', 'Sam lives in america']`.
I want to print True if word `'America/america'` is present in both the string or else print False. Need to check for the case sensitivity as lower or upper. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If maybe you want to check multiple words, you can create list of words and use `any`.

```
chk = ['America', 'americ']

res = [any(c in v1['country1'] for c in chk) for k1,v1 in Data.items()]
print(res)

# If you want to check and print
if all(res):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

---

```
[True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to do the case insensitive comparison, and then [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) on boolean values:

```
res = all("america" in v1['country1'].lower() for k1, v1 in Data.items())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
True
```